# Fast way to read all registry values

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I'm writing a utility that needs to create a list of all registry values in HKCR. I am doing this using a recursive function:

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Read(Registry.ClassesRoot, list);

static void Read(RegistryKey root, IDictionary<string, string> values)
{
    foreach (var child in root.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (var childKey = root.OpenSubKey(child))
        {
            Read(childKey, values);
        }
    }            

    foreach (var value in root.GetValueNames())
    {
        values.Add(string.Format("{0}\\{1}", root, value), (root.GetValue(value) ?? "").ToString());
    }
}
```

This works fine, but it takes a good chunk of time (20 seconds on my PC). Is there a faster way to do this, or is this as good as it gets?

Comment: It takes 7 seconds just to export it to a file under regedit on my pretty *new* installation. I'm pretty sure this is mostly just registry speed, or there being a lot of entries. How big does the dictionary end up?

Comment: While I don't know what the impact or concurrency limitations reading from the registry might have, you could try to switch the Dictionary to a ConcurrentDictionary and then Parallel your foreach loop to see if that speeds you up any. Of course this would be a waste if you're not running on a multi-core machine.

Comment: @JonSkeet 150,000ish entries.

Comment: @JonB: Okay, in that case it probably *is* the registry rather than the result processing.

Comment: @DanielGraham - I get an `IOException` after the first few hundred keys. I'm thinking it's a handle issue or something like that.

Comment: I suppose a better question would be why need all of that data in memory at the same time. If you are going to be doing something with each piece, why not use an enumeration and process each one in turn?

Comment: Why not try it in Powershell? there are cmdlets for this registry stuff :)

Comment: What other way is there to access the register other then read the register?

Comment: Have you benchmarked the registry with other programs that read it? This would could help you know whether it is the registry's size or your program/.NET. Have you tried iterating as opposed to recursion? How deep does the registry hierarchy go?

Comment: @RyanGates regedit takes just as long to export. I was hoping there was some kind of a fast way to read through the registry, but it appears not.

Comment: I used a List<> with a custom class of 2 fields (name/value) and used for loops instead of foreach, passed the list byref in the recursive function and got it down from 7 seconds to 5 seconds. I had to add in some error checks as the recursive function sometimes passed in a null root object and there was an exception on the dictionary add cause of a duplicate entry in my registry. So i think you are really doing all you can - there isn't a huge amount of room for improvement.

Comment: I changed the loops to Parallel.For()'s which got it down to 2 seconds from 7 seconds - (thanks Daniel). Note that i have a hex core cpu however.

Comment: Lastly - Export of classes root from RegEdit takes ~5seonds for comparison

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information in the registry and as others have noted here - speed can be an issue. If you want a list of registry settings to display in a tree-like view for the user to browse through, a better solution might be to scan the top level entries first, then as the user navigates through the tree, so you scan for those child values/settings as the tree node is opening.

I suspect this is how Microsoft's own regedit works.