# How to take the backup of all Windows Registry keys in c#

Tags: c#, registry

I want to take the backup of all registry keys at once using c#. I search for it but a lots of hints for a specific registry key backup but not for all keys. So if any one knows that how to take backup of all registry keys or any method to export all registry in c# kindly tell me. Thanks

Comment: You probably need to shell out to `regedit` to do the work for you. But what do you mean by "all" registry keys? Everything under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`? Everything under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (which would raise questions about permissions)? Are you wanting to back up the registry of *other* users besides the current user?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386017/fast-way-to-read-all-registry-values

Comment: yes i am taking backup of all registry keys besides the current user.

Comment: In general, [you **cannot** do anything with the registry for any user other than the current user](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/30/434209.aspx). `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` are the only things you can (reliably) work with (unless this is an internal tool and you know it can *never possibly* be run in any environment with roaming profiles).

Comment: And if i want to take backup of registry of current user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more search i found two solutions the first one is [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13386017/fast-way-to-read-all-registry-values)
And the second one is by using SendKeys. Now here is my code to export all registry keys.
But for doing this first you have to start your visual studio as administrator and then start regedit then run this code.

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();
string title = "";
foreach (Process process in processlist) {
    title = process.MainWindowTitle;
    if (title == @"Registry Editor" && process.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero) {
        SetForegroundWindow(process.MainWindowHandle);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%+F+E");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%+A");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%+S");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SendKeys.SendWait("TEST");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%+S");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        SendKeys.SendWait("%+{TAB}");
        break;
   }
}
```

And the supported functions are

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```